# Trying to build if else statements based on flavor of class constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I have a method that takes a List and another class object as its arguments. I want to iterate through the list based on the class object that I am passing into the method. The class has three different constructors. One of them takes Date objects, the other takes strings, and the third takes ints. In my method, I would like to do different things depending on which constructor is being used for the class object being used. Is there a way to do this? Is there a way I can do an if else statement that checks for the type of class object (based on constructor) being used?

For CodeWarrior: Here are constructor examples:

```
    public DateRange(Date date1, Date date2){

}

public DateRange(String string1, String string2){

}

public DateRange(int month, int year){

}
```

Then say I have a method like this:

```
public static List<Schedule> getSchedule(List<Schedule> schedules, DateRange dateRange) {
    List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    for (Schedule scheduleTime : schedules){
        if
```

I would like to set up the method to design the if statements to somehow check which type of the DateRange had been used, and do different things based on that.

Comment: Please post some code and show us what the class and method look like.

Comment: I have added specific examples of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

Modify your DateRange class so it can tell you how it was created:

```
public class DateRange {
    private final Object obj1;
    private final Object obj2;
    public DateRange(Date date1, Date date2) {
        obj1 = date1;
        obj2 = date2;
    }
    public DateRange(String string1, String string2) {
        obj1 = string1;
        obj2 = string2;
    }
    public DateRange(int month, int year) {
        obj1 = Integer.valueOf(month);
        obj2 = Integer.valueOf(year);
    }
    public boolean isDate() { return obj1 instanceof Date; }
    public boolean isString() { return obj1 instanceof String; }
    public boolean isInt() { return obj1 instanceof Integer; }
}
```

Here is the calling/checking syntax:

```
public static List<Schedule> getSchedule(List<Schedule> schedules, DateRange dateRange) {
    for (Schedule scheduleTime : schedules) {
        if(dateRange.isDate()) {
            // Do something based on the Date constructor.
        } else if(dateRange.isString()) {
            // Do something based on the String constructor.
        } else if(dateRange.isInt()) {
            // Do something based on the int constructor.
        }
    }
    return schedules;
}
```

Another option requiring further modification of your `DateRange` class would be to use inheritance to make a family of `DateRange` classes based on the constructor type. The base `DateRange` class would have an abstract method akin to `doSomething()` which would be provided by each of the inherited `DateRangeDate`, `DateRangeString`, and `DateRangeInt` classes. Then, you might not even have to process through the if tree in your iteration.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can obtain the type of constructor used to instantiate the object... but what you can do, is in each type of constructor set a specific parameter you'll check for later. For example, you could have a boolean variable for each constructor (all initially false). If a certain constructor is called, set it's respective variable to true. Or alternatively, set an integer field to a specific number for each constructor and later check the value of that field.

Comment: Good idea. Barring any other answer that addresses the issue directly, this is what I'll go with.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will not store which version of constructor was used to instantiate an object. This is some information that you will have to store somehow and code accordingly. For the example that you posted, try this

```
//DateRange.java

public class DateRange{

    private int constructorType;

    public DateRange(Date date1, Date date2){
         constructorType = 1;
    }

    public DateRange(String string1, String string2){
         constructorType = 2;
    }

    public DateRange(int month, int year){
        constructorType = 3;
    }

    public int getConstructorType(){
          return constructorType;
    }
}
```

This is the getSchedule() function:

```
    public static List<Schedule> getSchedule(List<Schedule> schedules, DateRange dateRange) {
    List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<Schedule>();
    for (Schedule scheduleTime : schedules){

        //use switch instead of if
        switch(dateRange.getConstructorType()){
           case 1: System.out.println("First constructor was called"); break;
           case 2: System.out.println("Second constructor was called"); break;
           case 3: System.out.println("Third constructor was called"); break;
           default: System.err.println("Something is wrong. Unknown constructor type"); break;
        }
    }
}
```